# Pyinstaller doesn't recognize docx2pdf library

Tags: python, console, pyinstaller, exe

my issue is that i've been trying to make an exe file with a .py that I created, but it doesn't work. I executed the converted .exe file from the console to see the log and I got this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "professors.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 531, in exec_module
  File "docx2pdf\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
  File "importlib\metadata.py", line 551, in version
  File "importlib\metadata.py", line 524, in distribution
  File "importlib\metadata.py", line 187, in from_name
importlib.metadata.PackageNotFoundError: docx2pdf
[6940] Failed to execute script professors
```

I've been reading about the issue and it seems that pyinstaller doesn't recognize the docx2pdf import. I read in a website that I have to add it in a folder called site-packages, but it is supposed to have another folder inside called pyInstaller, which is not there. I also tried adding the folder manually but it still didn't work. I also tried with the --hidden-imports method but im not sure how to exactly use it.
I will have to apply this to other imports that I have also.
Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I had a identical issue. I removed lines 7-13 from the docx2pdf module:

```
try:
     # 3.8+
     from importlib.metadata import version
except ImportError:
     from importlib_metadata import version

__version__ = version(__package__)
```

and line 119...

```
        print(__version__)
```

After that, it worked. Modifying the module probably isn't the best solution, and of course I'd recommend backing up the module before modifying it, but I hope it works for you too.

Comment: This worked for me. Although I just commented those lines out instead of deleting them.